# (Xiaomi Mi 9 Lite) Mobile data turns off automatically when screen is off!

Tags: battery-life, mobile-data, xiaomi, miui, xiaomi-mi9

I have an issue with Mi 9 Lite, when I lock my phone, mobile data turns off automatically after a short period of time, it will turn on as soon as the screen turn on, I tried to enable "Mobile Data Always Active" in developers options but still the same!
Does anyone knows how to disable this?

Comment: Are you using some apps to put the device into doze faster? Apps like Naptime have this option

Comment: @beeshyams Nope!